# What does it mean to be known at compile time? Constant expressions

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, constexpr

I'm confused to what it means to be known at compile time. From the code below, can the compiler not calculate the value of `n` even if I have passed a constant literal value 90 as an argument? Why does it give me an error that expression must have a constant value

```
constexpr int MAX_expr = 100;
const int MAX = 90;


void foo(int n)
{
    constexpr int cExpr1 = MAX_expr + 7;
    constexpr int cExpr2 = n + 7;

    constexpr int cExpr1 = MAX + 7;
    constexpr int cExpr2 = n + 7;

    const int cExpr1 = MAX_expr + 7;
    const int cExpr2 = n + 7; 

    const int cExpr1 = MAX + 7;
    const int cExpr2 = n + 7;
}

int main() {
    foo(90);
    const int i = factorials(90);
}
```

With that same logic, shouldn't  factorials(int i) give an error because it does not know what argument is going to be passed therefore, the compiler won't be able to compute what is going to be returned?

```
constexpr int factorials(int i) { 
    return i > 1 ? i * factorials(i - 1) : 1; 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The `constexpr` keyword can be confusing. It can be applied to both variables and functions, but with totally different meanings, except that they both have something to do with constant expressions.

A variable declared with `constexpr` must be initialized by a constant expression. In your code, `n + 7` is not a constant expression because the value of `n` is not known until the function is called and may vary from one call to the next. What if the user entered some integer, and then you passed that integer to `foo`? Obviously, that number plus 7 is not something you can call "known at compile time". Because of that, a function definition such as `foo` is not allowed. You cannot promise the compiler that you will only ever pass a constant expression argument. If you can, then promote `n` to a template parameter, and the code will work.

In contrast, `constexpr` applied to a function doesn't guarantee that calling the function produces a constant expression. It *allows* the function to be called in a constant expression, and places constraints on the definition in order to make this possible. While `factorial` will certainly not produce a constant expression if given a runtime argument, it will produce a constant expression if given an integer constant expression as an argument (assuming no overflow). Thus, unlike initializers of `constexpr` variables, a `constexpr` function is allowed to contain constructs that may or may not have compile-time constant values.